# Is <Password Type="">*****</Password> in XML is correct or not, if correct then what is the meaning of this?

Tags: xml, typescript, tags, passwords

I am having a XML in which I have *****, here type is just a blank string so what it means that?

Answer (score 0):

It's correct XML (at least if you replace the typographical quotes by ASCII quotes: `<Password Type="">****</Password>`).

As to what it means, XML means whatever the sender and recipient agree to make it mean. Consult the documentation for the particular XML vocabulary or document type.